# Change the color of a button in a dynamically created 2D array

Tags: asp.net, arrays, vb.net, button

For my homework, I was asked to create a checkerboard comprised of buttons. The size of this checkerboard is determined by the user through textboxes. The colors of the buttons in the checkerboard alternate between red and blue. If the user clicks on one of the buttons, it must change its color to either red or blue (depending on the current color).  In addition, clicking on a button must toggle the color of every button in that row.

My color array contains two dimensions (`rowInteger`, `colInteger`) which use the textbox values entered by the user.

My code for clicking on one of the dynamically created buttons is as follows:

```
Protected Sub tempBtn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim thisButton As Button = CType(sender, Button)

    For i As Integer = color.GetLowerBound(0) To color.GetUpperBound(0)
        For j As Integer = color.GetLowerBound(1) To color.GetUpperBound(1)
            If thisButton Is color(i, j) Then
                color(i, j).BackColor = Drawing.Color.Black
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

**Note that I changed the color to black strictly for testing purposes**

My code for creating the  buttons is as follows:

```
Private Sub createTable()
    Dim tempBtn As Button
    checkerBoard.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Groove
    checkerBoard.BorderWidth = Unit.Pixel(2)
    checkerBoard.Controls.Clear()

    For rowInteger = 0 To CInt(rowTxtBox.Text) - 1
        Dim newTableRow As New TableRow
        checkerBoard.Controls.Add(newTableRow)

        For colInteger = 0 To CInt(colTxtBox.Text) - 1
            Dim newTableCell As New TableCell
            tempBtn = New Button
            If colInteger Mod 2 = rowInteger Mod 2 Then
                tempBtn.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red
            Else
                tempBtn.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Blue
            End If

            tempBtn.Width = 200
            tempBtn.Height = 200
            AddHandler tempBtn.Click, AddressOf tempBtn_Click
            newTableCell.Controls.Add(tempBtn)
            newTableRow.Controls.Add(newTableCell)

            ReDim color(rowInteger, colInteger)
            color(rowInteger, colInteger) = tempBtn
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

When I run my website and click on a button, its color becomes transparent.  Why is this the outcome? I am able to change the color of an individual button (by altering the color of thisButton), but if I try changing its color using the code above, it simply does not work.

**EDIT: After running it again a few hours later, the color does not change at all.  I believe there may be an error in my solution, but I can't tell what it is**

Comment: `When I run my website` doe this mean asp?

Comment: yes. Our class uses ASP.NET in VB2010

Comment: I would edit the question to add an ASP tag (that seems likely to be where the issue is) so the right people look at it.  If you cant edit it, delete it and ask again with an ASP tag and a bit more clarity that it is ASP/Web.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Can you provide the code you are using to generate the buttons?

Comment: try calling your `createTable()` Sub inside `Page_Init` Sub